# JS / React / Redux / setTimeout () usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Функция updateList вызывается каждый раз при изменении поля input, получая event в качестве аргумента.
Как сбросить интервал запроса reqFn внутри updateList, для случаев когда поле input будет изменяться чаще, чем 1000 мс?

```
updateList = (e) => {
    let query = e.target.value;
    let reqFn = function(){
      axios.get(`https://typeahead-js-twitter-api-proxy.herokuapp.com/demo/search?q=${query}`)
        .then((response) => {
          //console.log(response);
          let getRq = this.props.onUpdateList.bind(this, response.data);
          getRq(); // or: //this.props.onUpdateList(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }.bind(this);

    setTimeout(reqFn, 1000);
  }
```

Пытаюсь добиться аналогичного поведения:
https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Comment: может лучше повесить eventlistener 'input', вместо таймаута?

Comment: @NeedHate, вообще-то `updateList` и есть этот подписчик. Таймаут для того, чтобы сервер запросами не спамить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
updateList = (e) => {
    ...

    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(reqFn, 1000);
}
```